# Brightness control in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, amd-radeon

I've got an Asus X54HR notebook that has an AMD HD7400M video card. I installed the latest drivers from http://asus.com/ru/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X54HR/. When I'm trying to turn down the brightness by using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the screen goes black after 50%.

Any ideas on how to lower the brightness below 50%?

Comment: Did this work correctly before you updated the drivers? If so, have to tried to revert back to older drivers? Have you tried to download drivers from amd.com?

Comment: I'm installed clean Windows 8.1, and brightness controler didn't worked. And yes, I tried drivers fro amd.com, result will bi similar.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I am glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing AMD Graphics Driver Version V9.003.0.0000 w8 x64 from [asus.com](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X54HR/HelpDesk_Download/)